# How do I get the period difference for each item in the table in PowerBI desktop?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

As seen below, I need to find the difference in quantities for each individual fruits with respect to the previous value. I have previously tried using in built Power BI functions like "PreviousDay()" but haven't found success yet.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create these below 2 **Measure** for your purpose-

```
Pervious_Quantity = 

Var current_row_date = MIN(your_table_name[Date])
var previous_date = 
CALCULATE(
    MAX(your_table_name[Date]),
    FILTER(
        ALLEXCEPT(your_table_name, your_table_name[Fruit]),
        your_table_name[Date] < current_row_date
    )
)

RETURN 
CALCULATE(
    SUM(your_table_name[Quantity]),
    FILTER(
        ALLEXCEPT(your_table_name, your_table_name[Fruit]),
        your_table_name[Date] = previous_date
    )
)
```

```
Difference = min(your_table_name[Quantity]) - if([Pervious_Quantity] = BLANK(),0, [Pervious_Quantity])
```

Here is the final output-

[image]